# How to tell the containing object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data and I was wondering if there was a way to determine the parent object of a nested object. For example, take this structure:

```
Vehicles[]
 ForSaleCars[]
  Car{}
   Make
   Model
   Year
 SoldCars[]
  Car{}
   Make
   Model
   Year
```

Assume that this is in `var json = ;` and has been filled with some data. It is easy to access the second car in the ForSaleCars array like this:

```
var secondCar = json.Vehicles.ForSaleCars[1];
```

At this point, **solely** from the `secondCar` variable, is it possible to tell it came from `ForSaleCars` and not `SoldCars`?

The reason I ask is that I am traversing a json object graph recursively and it would be nice to see which parent the object had *without* tracking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At this point, solely from the secondCar variable, is it possible to tell it came from ForSaleCars and not SoldCars?

No. JavaScript doesn't automatically track where a reference was copied from.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You can maintain hash instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are copying from the parent, and JavaScript won't track what the parent reference used to be. If you want to be able to track it, you will need to add a reference:

```
var secondCar = json.Vehicles.ForSaleCars[1];
secondCar.parent = json.Vehicles;
```